# NodeJS | How to not allow creation of an Object if constructor parameter has been used

Tags: node.js, class, object

My wording of the question probably butchered what I was trying to say; I'll just attach my code below:

```js
class Game {
    constructor(userID) {
        if ( /* an object has not been created with this userID */ ) {
            console.log("Game with this ID already exists");
        }

        else {
            this.gameID = userID;
            console.log("Created Game");
        }
    }
}

const gameOne = new Game(1234);   // "Created Game"
const gameTwo = new Game(1234);   // "Game with this ID already exists"
const gameThree = new Game(1235); // "Created Game"
```

Is there a way to check other objects that have been created from a class, or should I just store all the ID's in an array and check that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to track which games have been created already.

It's not entirely clear what you want to happen when a game is created that has the same id as an existing game, but you could just return the existing game instance:

```
class Game {
  static #ids = {};

  constructor(userID) {
    const game = Game.#ids[userID];
    if (game) {
      console.log("Game with this ID already exists");
      return game;
    }
    Game.#ids[userID] = this;
    this.gameID = userID;
    console.log("Created Game");
  }
}
```

Or, instead of `return game`, throw an error.

Comment: this works thanks, mind if i ask what the hashtag in the names do?

Comment: @sofabeddd they denote [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).